# if a is not an element in a list how to print?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i created a list like this:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5]
number = input("Choose a number from 1 to 5: ")
```

Now I want to say: 
if the number is inside the list: print("ERROR"),
if the number is not inside the list: print(number)

So if I type 2 it will print me the 2, if I type 1 it will print me ERROR

How am I doing that?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is it how to determine if the number is in the list?

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking something like the below example

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5]
number = input("Choose a number from 1 to 5: ")
if int(number) in my_list:
    print("error. . . . ")
else:
    print(int(number))
```

And when you run it this is how it works

> Choose a number from 1 to 5: 2
>
> 2
>
> Choose a number from 1 to 5: 1
>
> error. . . .

Answer (score 1):

First you need to take user input as `int` and then check if the number entered by user is present in `my_list` or not.

```
my_list = [1, 3, 5]
number = int(input("Choose a number from 1 to 5: "))


if number in my_list:
  print('Error')
else:
  print(number)
```